# installing opencv 2.2 in a different directory

Tags: opencv

I had already installed opencv 2.4.2 on my ubuntu 12.04 lts system. But now I have such a situation that I should install opencv 2.2.0 also. I would like to keep opencv 2.4.2. Is it possible?

Reason: I should use econ ECAM32 usb web cam to take images using opencv program but opencv 2.4.2 is not supporting this cam. But opencv 2.2 is supporting this cam.

I would like to hear how we can install opencv 2.2 on system in any other directory, I would prefer on folder in home directory,so that installation should not damage opencv 2.4.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see why not. `ubuntu 12.04` has `opencv 2.3` in it's repository therefore I'm assuming you have installed from the source. when you compile the source you should check `./configure --help` first which would probably give you an option for installation directory. It usually looks like:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/opencv2.2
```

let me know how you proceed..

Comment: ahh ok, but still I'm guessing there's an option to set the installation directory.

Comment: yes there is an option in cmake to set the installation path..like install_prefix....So do I need to create seperate folder for lib and include files......After that how can I link the libraries....?

Comment: I feel like you can put lib and include files under the same directory but I don't have a machine to test it. you can then compile your source with something like `g++ test.cpp -o test -I$HOME/opencv2.2/include -L$HOME/opencv2.2/lib -lopencv`. Alternatively you can add those directories to `$CPP_INCLUDE_PATH` and `$LIBRARY_PATH` respectively and do the compilation with just `g++ test.cpp -o test -lopencv`.